# Float divs, treat like rows

Tags: php, html, css

I have something like:

```
<div id="container">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

I've set the container to a clear fix and floated the divs inside the container, like this:

[image]

However, when I have additional text in a div, I'd **like** it to push the other divs down as if they were a row, like this:

[image: the divs should work like "rows" if possible]

Instead, because of the floats, I'm getting something more like this:

[image]

I'm just wondering as to the best way to go about this. I **could** put a wrapper around each "row", like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    </div>
    div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But that seems to be a lot of extra non-semantic divs...plus if I am generating the divs dynamically (through a list-view in a cms) then I have to add extra code to count each multiple of three divs...

Comment: please make a fiddle for current scenarios. Thanks

Comment: are you opposed to any javascript?

Comment: you have to see this : [Equal Height Columns with Cross-Browser CSS](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OOOh! Metro Tiles :)

this might be an old (3-year old) post but still explains nicely how to do the float height consistently cross-browser.

http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: Thanks! I just saw that and was going to delete this question...but I'll hit the check mark instead.

Comment: Oh neat, so it doesn't have to be a list then?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And then in your css file:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

One pure-CSS approach would be to clear every third div using the [`nth-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/nthchild.html) selector:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container div:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear:left;
}
<style>
```

This will not work in older versions of IE, however.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a clear class like below between each row of divs. However this doesn't always work older browsers. What you've done with row classes is the best practice in my belief.

```
.clear
 {
   display:block;
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   clear:both;
   height:1px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you want a new row, put the following:

```
<br style="clear: both; height: 0;" />
```